# VirtualBox Networking: 3G connections & VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, virtualbox

I hope someone can help me, I have a Windows 7 host & a Windows Server 2003 client. The host machine is connected to the internet using a 3G connection and is also connected to a VPN through the afore mentioned 3G connection.

Having attached the single network adapter to NAT, how do I get it to access resources on the VPN or as second price, access the internet?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If the VPN is already running on the host, then the NAT VM will also have the same access.

Comment: On the host the VPN is running and the host is able to access the internet & resources on the VPN, but the client can't even access the internet.

Comment: Hopefully when you mention "client" you are actually referring to the VM??? If the VM is able to access the Internet when the VPN is NOT running,then you might need to take a closer look at the IP plans of the VPN (remote end network) versus that of the VB NAT - there may be an IP plan conflict.

Comment: Hehe yes, by client I meant guest. But that just it, the guest is unable to connect to the internet or the VPN, regardless if the host is connected to the VPN or not.

Comment: Is networking working correctly with the guest OS (which adapter type - Intel, AMD, etc.)? What is the IP of the guest OS?

Comment: At my office I use a bridged adapter mapped to a Intel Pro/1000 MT. It works perfectly. A colleague suggested that I shut down the guest OS, change the attachment to NAT, connect to the VPN on my host, then starting up the guest OS. I will give it a try and report back.

Comment: In most cases your ISP will not assign you multiple IPs for a single connection (especially wireless ISPs), so if your guest is bridging, then that is probably the issue (it should be NATting the wireless connection).